# How can I get only the first line from a string?

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio

example:

```
string str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.";

string firstline;
```

How can I get just the first line from the string "str" into the string "firstline"?

Comment: couldn't be easier:  `new StringReader(str).ReadLine();`  @TimRogers answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming your string really contains new lines (`\r` and `\n`), you can use:

```
string line1 = str.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: this creates too much unneeded string objects and can easily fail on very large input

Comment: @SargeBorsch, I see three lines and OP is not talking about GB of daa so I believe it no such a big deal

Comment: @KonradKokosa - That may be true at the moment, but data has a way of expanding over time. It's much better to have a solution that will scale from the start than to have to figure out where that sudden increase in memory usage is coming from sometime in the future.

Comment: It would have been nice if Split had returned an IEnumerable<string>.

Comment: You could use the second parameter for string.Split(Char[], Int32) to define the max number of substrings to return. This will limit the array size.Put 2 there and the first line goes to first item and the rest of the lines to second item.

Comment: You would never do this.  It's just  new StringReader(str).ReadLine();  @TimRogers answer

Answer (score 100):

.NET already has a line-reader: `StringReader`. This saves worrying about what constitutes a line break, and whether there are any line breaks in the string.

```
using (var reader = new StringReader(str))
{
    string first = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

The using statement is used for disposing any non-managed resources consumed by the `reader` object. When using C#8 it can be simplified like so:

```
using var reader = new StringReader(str);
string first = reader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: This needs to be higher rated.

Comment: `StringReader` inherits a `Dispose` method from `TextReader`, and so you should wrap the call inside a using statement to make sure it is being disposed. Looking at the internals, omitting the `Dispose` call actually makes no difference (there is no unmanaged resource to free), but it is still a better practice to dispose when a type implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Sent a bounty to the best answer.  @Daniel why don't you add that suggestion in with an edit?

Answer (score 60):

Instead of `string.Split` I would use `string.Substring` and `string.IndexOf` to get only the first line and avoid unnecessary `string[]` with the entire input string.

```
string firstline = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine));
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the string does not contain a newline character.

Comment: correct that why i made 1 more check, `if(str.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)) > -1)` and to avoid checking twice i make a var & save the index

Answer (score 21):

`String.Split` will create a whole array of substrings, which is wasteful for your requirement. I would suggest using an index-based approach:

```
int index = str.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '\r', '\n' });
string firstline = index == -1 ? str : str.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 7):

Using LINQ you can have a simple solution which avoids the overhead of initially splitting the entire string into a collection of strings.

```
string first = new string(str.TakeWhile(c => c != '\n').ToArray());
```

Answer (score 5):

Single-line solution:

```
string firstline = str.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Here the second argument (=2) means that after finding the first line, splitting the line further into an array is no longer necessary, therefore it works faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regex`:

```
string line = new Regex("[^\r\n]*").Match(str).Value;
```

By default, the `Regex` is not multiline, so it matches just the first line. (Unfortunately, regex `.*` may include CR, see comments bellow, `[^\r\n]*` is more robust.)  You may put the `Regex` in the static variable if used often, it's thread safe:

```
static readonly FIRSTLINE_REGEX = new Regex("[^\r\n]*");
```

Comment: Seems you forgot the input string. I assume you meant: `string line = new Regex(".*").Match(str).Value;`

Comment: With MS-style line breaks, the captured string will include the CR that precedes LF. To exclude the CR, use `"[^\r\n]*"` as regex.

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks, your both suggestions are right. I've changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your string is invalid. You can't have a multine line string without using [*verbtaim string literal*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

You can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
 string str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
              consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor 
              invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At                vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.";
var array = str.Split('\n');
Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
```

Output will be;

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/hcmXAN)</kbd>.

Comment: Edit the question or comment it to if you think it's wrong and do not post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Split by new line character and access first element.

```
 string[] test = Regex.Split(str, "[\r\n]+");
 String firstline= test[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

An extension method could do it:

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns first line in a string or entire string if no linebreaks are included
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">String value</param>
    /// <returns>Returns first line in the string</returns>
    public static string FirstLine(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)) return str;
        var newLinePos = str.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine, StringComparison.CurrentCulture);
        return newLinePos > 0 ? str.Substring(0, newLinePos) : str;
    }
}
```

Call it with:

```
var firstLine = $"abc{Environment.NewLine}def".FirstLine();
```